# How do I add a user column to a custom list?

Tags: lookup-column, custom-list

I have created a custom list programatically. I want to add a field to it call User, this should be a lookup to the system Users. This will be like the default CreatedBy field.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First connect to your list, then get the 'Fields' property which is of type SPFieldCollection, then call the 'Add' method.  They key to answering your question is the SPFieldType enumerable. [Check out this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx) to see what types of fields you can add

```
list.Fields.Add("User", SPFieldType.User, isRequired);
```

[How to add a field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466360.aspx)

Comment: While this technically is correct, it might be helpful to include some more context for future users. :)